# Bootstrap select - add data-style attribute on click

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap and I'm looking to change the attribute "data-style" on my select boxes when they are invalid to "data-style=btn-danger" to highlight the invalid item.

So I would like this:

```
<select id="optionChoice" class="form-control select">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

To be changed to this when left unselected:

```
<select id="optionChoice" class="form-control select data-style="btn-danger">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

To do this, I'm using a Jquery function when my submit button is clicked. It includes this line:

```
 $('#optionChoice').attr('data-style', 'btn-danger');
```

But that's not changing anything.  If I manually add that attribute to the selectboxes, it shows properly, but I can't seem to get it added dynamically. I know the function is working because I also add a class to textboxes like so:

```
 $('#' + controltovalidate).addClass('error');
```

Which adds the class and changes the appearance of the textbox properly.  But that error class won't work with the bootstrap select, so I'm really trying to get this data-style attribute working.

Any ideas how I can get this attribute to be added dynamically?

Comment: `class="form-control select data-style="btn-danger"` looks like an Off-topic:Typo -- not enough double quotes.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently the bootstrap select is rendered in a way that you can't dynamically add a class using the usual .attr() call.

Instead you use this:

```
$('#optionChoice').selectpicker('setStyle', 'btn-danger');
```

More can be found here for those who need it: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="optionChoice" class="form-control select" data-style="btn-danger">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
</select>

we missed double quote in line closing class


<select id="optionChoice" class="form-control select data-style="btn-danger">
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I don't think that's the issue.  The data-style is not a class but an attribute that is added to the select item.  So the double quote was supposed was supposed to be there.  The issue seems to be something else

Comment: i will check and get you answer